# How to move tags when using git filter-branch?

Tags: git

After using git-filter-branch -- --all to change committers email I end up with almost perfect tree but tags are still attached to old tree (with old email). how can i move tags so i have complete tree with new email and all tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `--tag-name-filter cat` to get the tags moved.  Unfortunately, you need to do this at the same time as the original `filter-branch` command, as the mapping from old SHA-1 to new/different SHA-1 is only kept for the duration of the filter operation.

(You can of course repeat the `filter-branch` quite easily if you're working on a copy of the original repo: just make a new copy.  Or, you can use the `refs/originals/` name space to restore everything, but that's a bit trickier.)